# Java output if the data in the loop is not same as in first loop

Tags: java, loops

I'm doing a small program, and I ran into a problem.

Thing is I want to confirm that (in this case loop goes through 2 times) that the entered data was the **same** both times. If it's wrong it should output at the end that it's not correct.

```
     int yearInput;
     int monthInput;
     int i = 2;
     int x = 1;
     int inputvalid;
     int same = 0;


     while (x == 1) {
      while (i >= 1) {
       System.out.println(i);
       i--;
       System.out.println("enter year");
       yearInput = kb.nextInt();
       System.out.println("enter month");
       monthInput = kb.nextInt();
      }

      x--;
     }

     same = ???; 

     if(same==0){
     System.out.print("Both loop inputs are same");
     }
     else{
     System.out.println("Both loop inputs are not same");
     }

     }
```

While this program is just to show the problem, x and i values are variables in the real program, I just can't go through this segment.

Comment: I was thinking to add a counter somehow attached to the inputs?

Comment: You could save the data somewhere e.g. in an array.

Comment: Why would you use while loops instead of if statements? Right now you just have two infinite loops, because `x` and `i` never change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are first using two arrays which result in a nested loop which is probly something you don't want. If you wanted to check the results of two loops you'd create one loop with user inputs then store it in variable called something like **loopOneResult**. In the second loop you could do the same, then outside of both loops compare the results using the method equals or equalsIgnoreCase. This will surely tell you if the loops are the same. If this helps approve this answer :)

Comment: but what if there is like 100 loops? Is the only way to do that is using array?

Comment: Indeed. You could not use the loops the way you had it because it would be a nested loop in turn, making it a headache for you to use